# How to log saslauthd crashes

Tags: sasl, saslauthd

Is it possible to log saslauthd crash?

I had some crashes recently and there is messages that can't be found saslauth mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run saslauthd with the `-d` option. This will cause it to run in the foreground in debug mode and print lots of messages to the terminal it's running from.